# Looping through multiple URLs for an API call function

Tags: python, api, for-loop

I'm fairly new to python loops and need some assistance. I have a list of urls below. The numbers inside each of the URL represent a different product ID, and for each product ID(1,2,3 etc), the script runs a price update api call.

```
www.random.com/product/1/offer
www.random.com/product/2/offer
www.random.com/product/3/offer
```

I need to be able to loop through each of the URLs and perform the same task for each product id (1,2,3) - currently I have it setup as the following, but wondering how I can integrate a for loop into this. When I try with arrays + for loop it the script just executes the entire value inside the array when it calls the URL. Below is my code for a single URL.

```
    URL = 'www.random.com/product/1/offer'
    
    ua = UserAgent()
    #print(ua.chrome)
    header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}
    
    
    headers2 = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'charset': 'utf-8', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'xxx'}
    
    
    def main():
        response = requests.get(URL, headers=header)
        response_formatted = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8-sig').encode('utf-8'))
        price1 = response_formatted[0]["salePrice"]
        print(price1)
        discount_by=0.10
        new_discount_price= (price1-discount_by)
        print(new_discount_price)
        sku = response_formatted[0]["sku"]
```

So basically I would like to have 'URL' variable equal to a bunch of different URLs and loop the main call for each unique URL value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im new in this of python and stackoverflow but i recently did that so i think i can help you!!.

I did all in a function, i m sure its not the best but it works. What i  did is put all the values that i wanna change in a list.

In your case:

```
id=[1,2,3]
```

Then add ua and headers in the function and make a loop with the for loop:

```
def main():
listid=[1,2,3]
for i in listid:
    idlist=i
    ua = UserAgent()
    # print(ua.chrome)
    header = {'User-Agent': str(ua.chrome)}

    headers2 = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'charset': 'utf-8', 'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'xxx'}

    conn.request(f"GET", f"www.random.com/product/{idlist}/offer", headers=headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    data_formatted = json.loads(data.content.decode('utf-8-sig').encode('utf-8'))
    price1 = data_formatted[0]["salePrice"]
    print(price1)
    discount_by = 0.10
    new_discount_price = (price1 - discount_by)
    print(new_discount_price)
    sku = data_formatted[0]["sku"]
```

I dont know if it works but i m sure someone will fix it if its wrong, i hope i helped you!!

Comment: You can improve it using a try and except in case the id doesn t return any data, printing like its missing! or something like that =D.

Comment: DUDE, you are the best. I tweaked it a little but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Adrian, I got it. Solution was:

```
def main():

    listid=[1,2]
    for i in listid:
        idlist=i
        URL=f'https://www.random.com/products/{idlist}/offers'
      

        ua = UserAgent()
        #print(ua.chrome)
        header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}


        headers2 = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'charset': 'utf-8', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'xxx'}

        
        response = requests.get(URL, headers=header)
        response_formatted = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8-sig').encode('utf-8'))
```